# Background worker label changing per file

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I have a background worker that checks a list of files for byte size and MD5 hash. When it is checking them, I would like a label to say `Checking 'FileName'`.

This is my progress changed event:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var fileName = Convert.ToString(e.UserState);

        lblCheckFile.Text = string.Format("Downloading {0}", fileName);
        pBarFileProgress.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        gbFileProgress.Text = String.Format("Current File Progress: {0} %", e.ProgressPercentage);
    }
```

I have it saying `downloading` for when its actually downloading, but I would like it to say `Checking` and have a responsive progress bar for that as well. before it downloads.

Answer (score 2):

You can invoke Progress Changed event when checking file beside invoking it when downloading. But you need to pass more information through `UserState` object, for example state whether "Downloading" or "Checking" in addition to information about file name.

```
backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(0.5, new {state = "Checking", fileName = "SomeFile.jpg"});
//and later when downloading :
//backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(0.5, new {state = "Downloading", fileName = "SomeFile.jpg"});
```

Then in the event handler :

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var userState = (dynamic)e.UserState;
    var state = userState.state;
    var fileName = userState.fileName

    lblCheckFile.Text = string.Format("{0} {1}", state, fileName);
    pBarFileProgress.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    gbFileProgress.Text = String.Format("Current File Progress: {0} %", e.ProgressPercentage);
}
```